# TSQL, Remove batch of rows with same instanceID, except rows with certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, except

I have a large web-logging table, with log_instanceID, Log_id (Unique), Log_date, sevirity and other columns(non important).
I want to remove all rows of same Log_instanceID, expect instances that have at least one row with Log_Info value different then "INFO", i.e. "warn" or "Error".

```
SELECT COUNT(log_id) NoOfLogs, instance_id, severity, CAST(log_date  AS DATE) log_date
FROM log
WHERE instance_id = '3B2D8B77-1D4E-40F8-A274-5A1372E9178C'
group by instance_id, severity, cast(log_date  AS DATE)
```

Results - to keep

```
 NoOfLogs    |              instance_id                    |  severity    |   log_date
----------                --------------                   ----------       ----------
    93       |      3B2D8B77-1D4E-40F8-A274-5A1372E9178C   | **ERROR**    |  2019-11-03
    747      |      3B2D8B77-1D4E-40F8-A274-5A1372E9178C   |   INFO       |  2019-11-03

SELECT COUNT(log_id) NoOfLogs, instance_id, severity, CAST(log_date AS DATE) log_date
FROM log
WHERE instance_id = 'C24CE96F-65F1-44CF-8D91-5939091AF8AB'
GROUP BY instance_id, severity, CAST(log_date  AS DATE)
```

Results - to delete

```
 NoOfLogs    |              instance_id                    |  severity    |   log_date
----------                --------------                     ----------      ----------
    3        |      C24CE96F-65F1-44CF-8D91-5939091AF8AB   |   INFO       |  2019-05-13
```

I need to delete all instances with severity "INFO" only.

How can I extract only the instances with info only logs?

Answer (score 1):

A straight forward solution is `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery checking for the existence of a record of another severity then "INFO" for the same instance id.

```
DELETE FROM log
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM log x
                                     WHERE x.instance_id = log.instance_id
                                           AND x.severity <> 'INFO');
```

Comment: Thanks,
It make sense, though I don't trust "NOT EXISTS"  a 100%,
In some situations it might ignore the sub query results.
I'll run your script first with a select before deleting to validate no renegade instances are in the list.